# Referencing Groovy from Java with Gradle and Spring Boot results in"cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Component `DummyStorageRepository` and interface `StorageRepository` written in Groovy

```
class DummyStorageRepository implements StorageRepository {...
}
```

Now in my Application.java which is also a spring boot starter config I have

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements AsyncConfigurer { 
...
@Bean
public StorageRepository storageRepository() {
    return new DummyStorageRepository();
}
```

My Gradle.buid file is plain vanilla.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()            
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.8.RELEASE'
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'project-report'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

targetCompatibility = 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    baseName = 'service'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()        
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7:indy'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.1.8.RELEASE'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.8.RELEASE')
}
```

and my file structure is

```
src/main/groovy/com/app/repository/DummyStorageRepository.groovy, StorageRepository.groovy
src/main/java/com/app/Application.java
src/main/resources/...
```

This is the error

```
/app/Application.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
    public StorageRepository storageRepository() {
           ^
  symbol:   class StorageRepository
  location: class Application
```

If I convert Application.java to Application.groovy and move it to the groovy tree everything is compiled as expected. The same applies if I convert DummyStorageRepository.groovy and StorageRepository.groovy to java and move it into the java tree.
I am on gradle 2.1 if it of any matter.

Why to I get "cannot find symbol" error wehen referencing groovy from java?

**Update:**

I added manually a source set to my gradle.build, just to see what paths are scanned but the result stays the same.

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy']
        }
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }

    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/groovy','src/test/java']
        }
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move the Java file to the groovy folder, no need to rename

Comment: Also see docs for Groovy/Java joint compilation in the Groovy plugin chapter of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser according to http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/img/groovyPluginTasks.png compileGroovy depends on compileJava. I can not reference groovy from java because compile java needs to run before compile groovy. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. If you only ever have dependencies from Java to Groovy, you could invert the task dependency between `javaCompile` and `groovyCompile`, but it's probably safer (and easier) to use joint compilation.

Comment: I was reading Chapter 24 and what I understand is that joint compilation is enabled by default. So my initial gradle config should work.

Comment: @Vadimo joint compilation means, that both .java and .groovy are compiled by compileGroovy, if put in src/*/groovy

Comment: I have only <apply plugin: 'groovy'> in my gradle.build so everything is compiled(proxied) by groovy plugin I supose. Didnt know that joint compilation literally means put everything into one src directory mixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the credit for this answer should really go to @tim_yates, but the suggested solution and reasons given in the question's comments are all legitimate:

## Quick Solution:

Move all of your .java files under `src/main/groovy` and compile all files w/ the groovy compiler

## Reasoning:

In order to reference groovy code in java files AND java code in groovy files, you can't have a task dependency on `compileJava` in `compileGroovy`, or vice versa, so joint compilation using `compileGroovy` has to do both.

### References:

[Gradle User Guide - Groovy Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#groovy_plugin)

[Gradle compileGroovy dependency graph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/img/groovyPluginTasks.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Spring Tool Suite (STS`), then converting the project to a "`Groovy`" project using the

> right click project -> Configure -> Convert to Groovy

Project will also fix the problem because now the project uses the `compileJava + compileGroovy` as mentioned in the accepted answer above.

Comment: how is this possible in STS 3.8.3 RELEASE? Can .groovy and .java co-exist in same spring boot application?

Comment: I dont see an option in project properties to convert to Groovy